# How to connect to Wacom Bamboo Spark?

Tags: bluetooth, wacom

I bought a "Wacom Bamboo Spark" and a "Bluetooth Low Energy" / "Bluetooth Smart" capable USB dongle. With "hcitool lescan" I find the Wacom tablet and can even connect to it for a short period. But I have not figured out, which protocol the Wacom tablet uses to transfer the files.

Comment: with android-x86 I could connect to my notebook. So the bluetooth dongle works with bamboo spark

Comment: I've bought an http://www.iskn.co/ slate for which there will be soon a supported ubuntu driver, see for example this engineer comment:     http://support.iskn.co/hc/en-us/community/posts/206639449-Will-Ubuntu-be-supported-